# Set keyboard shortcut to open a new window of the current program

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Obviously I could use my mouse and open a new window by right clicking but I was hoping there is a way to set a keyboard shortcut to do so. For example, right now I am typing in firefox, it would be nice to have a keyboard shortcut to open a new firefox window. I could do this in both windows and on Mac, surely I can do it on Ubuntu 23.10 ? I have found in settings the keyboard shortcuts for resizing the windows but none for opening a new window

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, this is application dependent. In Firefox, it's Ctrl+n

Answer (score 0):

Opening new windows of applications is controlled by each individual application. There is no system wide shortcut, provided by the desktop environment, for this.

For Firefox in particular, the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> will open a new window. This convention is used by other applications as well, such as LibreOffice and the Gedit text editor.